# Who in the world am I?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> *I can fluff
>
>   I can smash
>
>   I can read
>
>   I can write*
>   *Turn me around
>
>   and I will scar*
>   *More than one
>
>   then I'm red and far*

**Bonus** (requires VERY specific knowledge):

> I am the next best girl in pink.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are a ...

> ... **ram**.

I can fluff

> Rams have wool.

I can smash

> Rams can butt. Battering rams can smash gates.

I can read, I can write

> RAM is random-access memory that can be both read from and written to.

Turn me around and I will scar

> Ram reversed is mar, which can mean to scar.

More than one then I'm red and far

> Mars is the red planet. (Answer provided by OP. I first had thought about more than one ram, which didn't get me anywhere useful, of course.)

Bonus (requires VERY specific knowledge):

> Or access to search egnines. `:)`

I am the next best girl in pink.

> Ram is one of the protagonists of the Japanese light novel [Re:Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re:Zero_%E2%88%92_Starting_Life_in_Another_World). She's a girl with pink hair.

Comment: Perfect! I guess for people who watch Re: Zero, this would be too easy. For the "More than one then I'm red and far", more than one means pluralize it -> Mars. #RemBestGirl

Comment: Oh, so the more than one is after turning around, which now is quite obvious. I don't watch Re:Zero, by the way, and didn't even know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> A cloud

I can fluff
I can smash

> Maybe a reference to Prince fluff in super Smash bros.

I can read
I can write

> referring to using clouds to upload and download data over the internet

I am lost on the other clues :(

Comment: Nice one! But not exactly the word I'm looking for. The other clues are just as important.